# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I already have a table employee with columns name(String),id(int),age(int).
I can't figure out where the syntax is wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recins (
    name1 IN employee.name%type ,
    id1 IN employee.id%type ,
    age1 IN employee.age%type
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee VALUES(name1,id1,age1);
END;
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `delimiter` statements.

Comment: that error message should have more specific location about where the error occurs, something like `NEAR 'END`

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN employee.name%type , id1 IN employee.id%type , age1 IN employee.age%type) AS
' at line 1 -- the rest of the message displayed by phpMyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table employee2
(
    name varchar(100) not null,
    id int not null,
    age int not null
);


DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE recins (
    IN name1 varchar(100),
    IN id1 int,
    IN age1 int
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee2 (name,id,age) VALUES(name1,id1,age1);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

-- test:
call recins('a',1,2);
```

delimiter is a special wrapper for stored procs, events, functions. `Delimiter ;` at the end of the stored proc sets it back to the normal/default delimiter of a semi-colon.

The above was tested.

Comment: thanks but i would also like to ask was i using the parameter%type command with a wrong syntax.

Comment: I have never seen such a thing. It has to be a valid mysql datatype. If it makes you feel any better, it is not uncommon for people starting out to waste hours just on the DELIMITER thing :p

Comment: silly me, i was confusing mysql with oracle. Thanks for the help